# Shell command not generating output file

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following line of code in my macro:

```
Shell("importFile.bat"), vbHide
```

Here's what I have in the importFile.bat:

```
ftp -n -i -g -s:import.ftp > C:\log.txt
```

For some reason whenever I run the macro, the log.txt file gets generated but the file is empty. But when I manually try to run the batch file, I see the output of the FTP command.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you flesh out the import.ftp and run it in the shell directly?

Comment: I tried that but now the log.txt file is not getting generated at all (Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:import.ftp > C:\temp\log.txt", vbHide)

Comment: Specify full paths to files. I say this 50 times a day.

Answer (score 0):

Tried as below.. i could able to see the out.txt with ftp data, i think the ftp command is not able get import.ftp file path in excel macro.. try giving full path. you can try with below code.

```
Sub ftp_button()

batfile = FreeFile

ftpbat = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.bat"
ftpout = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\out.txt"
ftpcmd = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\import.ftp" 'Existing ftp file - file contains one stmt "open 127.0.0.1"

If Dir(ftpbat) <> "" Then Kill (ftpbat)
If Dir(ftpout) <> "" Then Kill (ftpout)

Open ftpbat For Output As #batfile
Print #batfile, "ftp -n -i -s:" & ftpcmd; " > " & ftpout
Close #batfile

Shell (ftpbat), vbHide
```

End Sub